# Pandas минимум между 2 столбцами

Tags: python, pandas, max, min

Как добавить в пандас дата фрейм столбец с функцией min или max между значениями двух других столбцов?
Фрейм `df = pd.DataFrame({'First':[1, 3, 5], 'Second':[4, 4, 2]})`
Надо добавить колонку Third: `[1, 3, 2]`
Так не работает:

```py
df['Third'] = min(df.First, df.Second)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос: пример данных, ожидаемый результат и ваши попытки решения

Comment: Добавил. Что Вы можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 2):

Если функций несколько - например, минимум и максимум, удобно использовать `agg()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First':[1, 3, 5], 'Second':[4, 4, 2]})
df[['min', 'max']] = df.agg([min, max], axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
   First  Second  min  max
0      1       4    1    4
1      3       4    3    4
2      5       2    2    5
```

Можно и просто `min()`:

```
df['min'] = df[['First', 'Second']].min(axis=1) # если во фрейме есть столбцы, которые не нужно обрабатывать, то отбираем только нужные
df['min'] = df.min(axis=1) # если обрабатываем все столбцы
```

```
   First  Second  min
0      1       4    1
1      3       4    3
2      5       2    2
```

Методы применяем к оси `columns` или `1`: `axis=1`.
Новую колонку я бы не называл `Third`, поскольку оно не отражает того, что содержит минимум. Лучше назвать столбец соответственно примененной функции - min или max.